# Error on Simulate parachains in a test network

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo-local, polkadot-sdk

I am trying to Simulate parachains in a test network and following this [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/) but I am getting this error. Someone please advice what I am doing wrong?

```
Error:       Error: Command failed with exit code 1: bash -c ./binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0 export-genesis-state --chain /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-bcd6ef486af74db41e50399bd8c2ffb9_-81107-rmK1Gdgr2D7g/1001-rococo-local.json > /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-bcd6ef486af74db41e50399bd8c2ffb9_-81107-rmK1Gdgr2D7g/cfg/genesis-state-1001 && ./binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0 export-genesis-wasm --chain /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-bcd6ef486af74db41e50399bd8c2ffb9_-81107-rmK1Gdgr2D7g/1001-rococo-local.json > /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-bcd6ef486af74db41e50399bd8c2ffb9_-81107-rmK1Gdgr2D7g/cfg/genesis-wasm-1001
Error: Service(Client(Backend("IO error: While lock file: /Users/ganesholi/Library/Application Support/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0/chains/dev_local_testnet/db/full/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable")))

undefined
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Node'              │ /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-bcd6ef486af74db41e50399bd8c2ffb9_-81107-r… │
│ s logs:            │                                                                                                    │
│ m                  │                                                                                                    │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

 Error:      Error: Command failed with exit code 1: bash -c kill -9 
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav %
```

[image]

I am using

```
zombienet-macos version
1.3.68

ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot-sdk % git branch
  master
* release-polkadot-v1.1.0
```

[github link of parachain template](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/xcav-parachain)

Comment: Which version is your parachain?

Comment: I am using `release-polkadot-v1.1.0` for my parachain

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue you can follow here: [Error: Race when use multiple parachains in native (default concurrency)](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1237).

Until is fixed you can use the [workaround](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1237#issuecomment-1675507189) suggested by Javier:

Add the flag `-c 1` when running zombienet:

```
./zombienet-macos spawn config.toml -p native -c 1
```

The flag  `-c, --spawn-concurrency <concurrency>`, set the number of concurrent spawning process to launch.